# PyTorch Dataset Field for Sequence of Vectors (No Vocabulary)

Tags: python, pytorch, torchtext

I have a "simple" machine translation task where I have a sequence of vectors to be mapped to a word or two. (the vector is 258 dimensions)

For example:

- `[[1, ..., 2], [3, ..., 4]]` => "hello"
- `[[1, ..., 2], [3, ..., 4], [5, ..., 6]]` => "hello world"

For the target field, I am using `Field(eos_token="<eos>", is_target=True)`, which when batched does correctly give me a tensor with padding, in this case:

```py
tensor([
  [1, 1], # 1 is "hello"
  [2, 3], # 2 is "world", 3 is <eos>
  [3, 0], # 0 is <pad>
])
```

However, the `src` field is not being padded the same way, as it is `sequential`, but does not have a vocabulary (`Field(use_vocab=False)`).

When I read the `src` from the `BucketIterator`, in a batch of size > 1, I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "train.py", line 50, in train
>
> ```
> for b, batch in enumerate(train_iter):
> ```
>
> File "/torchtext/data/iterator.py", line 156, in **iter**
>
> ```
> yield Batch(minibatch, self.dataset, self.device)
> ```
>
> File "/torchtext/data/batch.py", line 34, in **init**
>
> ```
> setattr(self, name, field.process(batch, device=device))
> ```
>
> File "/torchtext/data/field.py", line 237, in process
>
> ```
> tensor = self.numericalize(padded, device=device)
> ```
>
> File "/torchtext/data/field.py", line 359, in numericalize
>
> ```
> var = torch.tensor(arr, dtype=self.dtype, device=device)
> ```
>
> **ValueError: expected sequence of length 258 at dim 2 (got 5)**

What I want to get is a tensor:

```py
tensor([
  [[1, ..., 2], [1, ..., 2]],
  [[3, ..., 4], [3, ..., 4]],
  [[5, ..., 6], [0, ..., 0]],
  [[0, ..., 0], [0, ..., 0]],
])
```

What I **think** I might have but don't know how to confirm is:

```py
tensor([
  [[1, ..., 2], [1, ..., 2]],
  [[3, ..., 4], [3, ..., 4]],
  [[5, ..., 6], 0],
  [0, 0],
])
```